# Transformation of data into list of objects of class in spark scala

Tags: scala, class, apache-spark, transformation

I am trying to write a spark transformation code to convert the below data into list of objects of following class, I am totally new to scala and spark and tried splitting the data and put them into case class but I was unable to append them back. Request your help on this.

Data :

```
FirstName,LastName,Country,match,Goals
Cristiano,Ronaldo,Portugal,Match1,1
Cristiano,Ronaldo,Portugal,Match2,1
Cristiano,Ronaldo,Portugal,Match3,0
Cristiano,Ronaldo,Portugal,Match4,2
Lionel,Messi,Argentina,Match1,1
Lionel,Messi,Argentina,Match2,2
Lionel,Messi,Argentina,Match3,1
Lionel,Messi,Argentina,Match4,2
```

Desired output:

```
PLayerStats{ String FirstName,
    String LastName,
    String Country,
    Map <String,Int> matchandscore
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already loaded data into an `RDD[String]` named `data`:

```
case class PlayerStats(FirstName: String, LastName: String, Country: String, matchandscore: Map[String, Int])

val result: RDD[PlayerStats] = data
  .filter(!_.startsWith("FirstName")) // remove header
  .map(_.split(",")).map { // map into case classes
    case Array(fn, ln, cntry, mn, g) => PlayerStats(fn, ln, cntry, Map(mn -> g.toInt))
  }
  .keyBy(p => (p.FirstName, p.LastName)) // key by player
  .reduceByKey((p1, p2) => p1.copy(matchandscore = p1.matchandscore ++ p2.matchandscore)) 
  .map(_._2) // remove key
```

Comment: @Bhushan glad it helped - you can accept / upvote the answer to let future readers know this was useful

Answer (score 0):

Firstly convert the line into key value pair say `(Cristiano, rest of data)`  then apply `groupByKey`  or `reduceByKey` can also work then try to convert the key value pair data after applying groupByKey or reduceByKey into your class by  putting value.  Take a help of famous word count program.

http://spark.apache.org/examples.html

Answer (score 0):

You could try something as follows:

```
val file = sc.textFile("myfile.csv")

val df = file.map(line => line.split(",")).       // split line by comma
              filter(lineSplit => lineSplit(0) != "FirstName").  // filter out first row
              map(lineSplit => {            // transform lines
              (lineSplit(0), lineSplit(1), lineSplit(2), Map((lineSplit(3), lineSplit(4).toInt)))}).
              toDF("FirstName", "LastName", "Country", "MatchAndScore")         

df.schema
// res34: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(FirstName,StringType,true), StructField(LastName,StringType,true), StructField(Country,StringType,true), StructField(MatchAndScore,MapType(StringType,IntegerType,false),true))

df.show

+---------+--------+---------+----------------+
|FirstName|LastName|  Country|   MatchAndScore|
+---------+--------+---------+----------------+
|Cristiano| Ronaldo| Portugal|Map(Match1 -> 1)|
|Cristiano| Ronaldo| Portugal|Map(Match2 -> 1)|
|Cristiano| Ronaldo| Portugal|Map(Match3 -> 0)|
|Cristiano| Ronaldo| Portugal|Map(Match4 -> 2)|
|   Lionel|   Messi|Argentina|Map(Match1 -> 1)|
|   Lionel|   Messi|Argentina|Map(Match2 -> 2)|
|   Lionel|   Messi|Argentina|Map(Match3 -> 1)|
|   Lionel|   Messi|Argentina|Map(Match4 -> 2)|
+---------+--------+---------+----------------+
```